# Grouping By subproperty

Tags: c#, .net, linq

OrderItems can have or not have preferences. I want to group my orderitems by preference.But only preference of one type(4) otherwise they should belong at "null" group.

This code works but  other coders are telling me that it sucks (but dont suggest a solution) . What could I do ?

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<Preference,OrderItem>> OrderItemsGrouped { 
    get {

        var grouped = OrderItems
            .GroupBy(item =>
            {
              var i = item.Preferences.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Preference.PreferenceGroup.Type == 4);
              if (i != null) return i.Preference;
              else
              {
                  return null;
              }
            })
            .OrderBy(k => { return k.Key == null ? -1 : k.Key.Order; });

        return grouped;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You cannot "group by preference" meaningfully unless `Preference` overrides `Equals`, because the default implementation uses reference equality (and therefore no preference would ever be equal to any other). Does it?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what the static type of `OrderItem.Preferences.First()` would be -- even though it should be a `Preference` by all that is right, from your code it looks like it's not (`i` is something pulled from `Orderitem.Preferences`, but it *has* a `Preference` instead of *being* one).

Even though that looks wrong, I 'm going to just ignore it and assume the type of `i` is `Foobar` from now on. I am going to treat `Foobar` as having properties `Preference` and `Order`, as the code implies.

The most straightforward solution would be to create a dummy `Foobar` object and use that as a placeholder:

```
var placeholder = new Foobar() { Preference = null, Order = -1 };
```

Then the body of the method could be simplified to

```
return OrderItems
       .GroupBy(item => item.Preferences.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                                          p.Preference.PreferenceGroup.Type == 4)
                        ?? placeholder)
       .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Order);
```

Of course this changes the return value in that the "null" group does not have a `null` key, but having a `null` key is probably a bad idea to start with because of its semantics. If the "null group" models something, then make `placeholder` a `static readonly` field so that the consumers can check against it.

Comment: i is an OrderItemPreference object .Its the glue.It is needed because Preference can have quantity and other properties.  OrderItemPreference   has a Property Preference and Preference belongs to a PreferenceGroup   . Preference has a property that points to its PreferenceGroup